# Can't update AppScript Gmail Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-editor

I'm creating a Gmail Addon and for some reason AppScript has stopped updating when I save my code. Up until last week I would make changes, save my code, refresh Gmail add the updates would be there. The addon is installed as a developer addon using the HEAD version.

First question, do I have to re-deploy or anything after making changes? As far as I can see in the documentation the approach above should work fine.

I'm using the Google Oauth2 library to login into an external service. It was all working fine last week and now I've just noticed these errors come up in the execution hints...

`Method Properties.deleteProperty invoked in the global scope.
File: Storage 
Line: 125
This function invocation will fail when the script is run as an Add-on in AuthMode.NONE.`

`Method Cache.remove invoked in the global scope.
File: Storage 
Line: 127
This function invocation will fail when the script is run as an Add-on in AuthMode.NONE.`

`Method ScriptApp.getScriptId invoked in the global scope.
File: Service 
Line: 36
This function invocation will fail when the script is run as an Add-on in AuthMode.NONE.`

I don't have access to the files that the errors are referring too though so how am I supposed to fix them?

Also if there are errors in the execution hints will that prevent any updates to the code? Is that the reason I wouldn't be seeing my updates come through?

I know the updates aren't working because I'm seeing nothing in the logs where I was before.

Really appreciate any help. I've spent hours going through the docs, SO and the issue tracker trying to figure this out.

Comment: Could you give some code snippets of where those errors are thrown (i.e. line 36, 125, 127)?

Comment: Hey @e.maguire unfortunately I can't as those errors are being thrown in files I don't have access to `File: Storage` and `File: Service`. I presume they are some sort of system files or something. They're not files that are in my project.